# How do deserialise XML that has an element of either XML or text

Tags: c#, xml

I am trying to deserialise some xml into an object that could be either well formed XML or straight text.  I only want to show this as text, so it doesn't need to be in some object that I need to access (i.e. I'll do a .ToString() to use it).

```
public class Entry
{
    [XmlAttribute]
    public string Label { get; set; }
    [XmlAttribute]
    public string Format { get; set; }
    [XmlAttribute]
    public string Context { get; set; }
    [XmlAnyElement]
    public XmlElement Data { get; set; }
}
```

It works OK if the `Data` element is XML:

```
<Entry Label="results" Context="XXXX">
  <Data>
    <XmlSerializableException >
      <Message>Transformation failed</Message>
    </XmlSerializableException >
  </Data>
</Entry>
```

But if the Data element is pure text, it doesn't deserialise (I get null in the field):

```
<Entry Label="results" Context="XXXX">
  <Data>
    Some plain text
  </Data>
</Entry>
```

Deserialisation function:

```
        var serializer = new XmlSerializer(typeof(Entry));
        var settings = new XmlReaderSettings { };
        var xmlReader = XmlReader.Create(fileName, settings);
        var graph = (Entry)serializer.Deserialize(xmlReader);
        return graph;
```

Comment: Try serialize your two different scenarios (Data is an element & Data is a string) and see what kind of XML is being generated.

Comment: Your `Entry` class seems to work perfectly.  See https://dotnetfiddle.net/ICIayj.  What's the problem?  Are you not accessing the text value of your `XmlElement` with the [`InnerText`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.xml.xmlelement.innertext.aspx) property?

Comment: As an aside, be sure to dispose the `xmlReader` by bracketing it in a  [`using`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/yh598w02.aspx) statement.